# How to find something within Visual Studio using the Regular Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio

I'd like to search within Visual Studio 2010 for any word containing "ati" but excluding any word containing "ation" or "static".

How would you write the regular expression?

Comment: Someone wrote the correct answer but removed it?  [^static|information|Serialization]ati

Comment: That matches sequences of 4 characters where the first is not one of `staic|nform` and the last three are `ati`. Your question asks for something else.

Comment: You don't want to match "action", but do you want to match something like "station"?

Comment: @TheLight I removed my answer due to the amount of downvotes it was getting - I might have misunderstood you - Can you give a list of words you want it to match?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it works:

```
((ati~(c))|(~(st)..ati))~(on)
```

This finds

> (`ati` preceeded by two characters that are not `st`, or not followed by `c`) not followed by `on`.

It's close, but it *won't* match `atic` preceeded by only 0 or 1 character(s) at the start of a line. (Edit: see below.)

Note that this only *matches* the `ati` (or `..ati` if the `ati` is followed by `c`) - if you're trying to match (and, say, replace) the *whole word*, this won't help. It'll just help you *find* these places.

Edit: The following will also match (start of line, zero or one characters, `atic`):

```
((ati~(c))|(~(st)..ati)|(^.ati)|(^ati))~(on)
```